# How to include losses due to lifetime degradation of PV panels in pvlib

Tags: pvlib

Is there a way to specify and include losses due to panel degradation into pvlib calculation of ac/dc power output? When trying to estimate e.g. 20-year performance, how to represent losses due to panel degradation? Is that done simply by reducing power output by a different factor each year or is there a better way to do it in pvlib?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the [pvsystem.pvwatts_losses](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/pvlib.pvsystem.pvwatts_losses.html#pvlib.pvsystem.pvwatts_losses) function? This will apply a uniform loss. You'd need to write your own functions to do anything more complicated than that with pvlib.

Also consider the [rdtools](https://github.com/NREL/rdtools) library.

Comment: Thank you. I have seen pvwatts_losses but was wondeing if there is something more complicated. I guess pvwatts will be enough. I will look into the rdtools.